# javascript, confirm > alert > redirect in sequence

Tags: javascript, html

im using bootbox and bootstrap

im creating a form which ask user for the confirmation, if confirm = true, then alert message and then only redirect. 
i found the solution which using window.alert, but it's ugly.

Here's what I have (using Bootstrap and BootBox; [jsFiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/UNGQ5/)):

HTML:

```
<a class="alert" href=#>Alert!</a>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).on("click", ".alert", function (e) {
    bootbox.confirm("Hello world!", function (result) {
        if (result) {
            bootbox.alert('User added');
            //window.alert('ok');   //dun wan to use this, because it's ugly                  
            window.open('http://google.com', '_self'); //fiddle can't run this line
        }
    });
});
```

but the fiddle cannot run the 'window.open'. u can try at your development tool.

the problem i face now is the page will direct to the new page WITHOUT waiting the user to response on the alert. how to solve it?

there are plenty of example/solution on internet on 'how to alert then redirect', i tried them but nothing is worked. my case here is different, it shows by confirmation > alert > navigate.

please advice, thank you.

Comment: Always include the relevant code and markup **in** the question, don't just link (not even to a fiddle). Links rot, and people shouldn't have to go off-site to help you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use callbacks as per [documentation](http://bootboxjs.com/documentation.html)

*Syntax*

```
bootbox.alert(str message, fn callback)
```

Example:

```
bootbox.alert('User added', function(){
    window.open('http://google.com', '_self');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Read documentation of bootbox. There is one line that you need: `bootbox.alert(message, callback)`, so you pass callback function :

```
function(){window.open('http://google.com', '_self');}
```